# Tomcat 8.5.40 does not work after Amazon linux O.S. upgrade to Version 3.1.6

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, tomcat8

I am a java developer, and our web application have been running on AWS Beanstalk over AWS EC2 instances with Java-8, Tomcat 8.5 and 64-bit Amazon Linux/3.0.1.
Recently, as per security team's recommendations,we had upgraded Amazon linux to version 3.1.6 with O.S. auto update option. 
After upgrading Amazon linux O.S. to 3.1.6, tomcat started giving 404 below error :

*Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.40*

After O.S upgrade, restarted tomcat server.

We did not make any other changes at application level and configuration level as well. In application logs, we did not find anything odd at coding level. But after O.S. upgrade it is showing below errors in applications logs:

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1185)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:82)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:228)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:191)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:113)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:69)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListObjectsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1553)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1271)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1055)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4247)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4194)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4188)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:823)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:792)
    at com.trivin.ltr.ArchiveImportThread.listKeysInBucket(ArchiveImportThread.java:717)
    at com.trivin.ltr.ArchiveImportThread.run(ArchiveImportThread.java:850)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

This is blocker issue for my work, so your help would be appreciated. 
if required I can provide more details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As your error message says, "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" not found. Check the jar files probably in "..WEB-INF/lib. Maybe the OS upgrade changed the lib location?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I double checked the required JAR file for SAXParser, and required xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar is present at WEB-INF/lib.
Other JARs are also being referred from same location. So not sure why it is giving "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" not found.